# How to group based on value in previous row?

Tags: r, group-by

edit: The answer below solved my initial question, but i did not mention that the list also includes individual vessels, and they need to be considered.

I have a list of vessels  and I want to create routes based on certain criteria. I have produced the following list, and I want to create a TRACKID for each route segment for each individual ship.

```
VESSEL  Date    Sailing/Port
1      01.02.2016   SAILING
1      02.02.2016   SAILING
1      03.02.2016   SAILING
1      04.02.2016   SAILING
1      05.02.2016   SAILING
1      06.02.2016   PORT
1      07.02.2016   PORT
1      08.02.2016   PORT
1      09.02.2016   PORT
1      10.02.2016   SAILING
2      11.02.2016   SAILING
2      12.02.2016   SAILING
2      13.02.2016   SAILING
2      14.02.2016   PORT
2      15.02.2016   PORT
2      16.02.2016   SAILING
```

If the ship is SAILING I want it to keep the same TRACKID until it enters a PORT. The first half of the positions in the PORT should be assigned to the same TRACKID as before entering the port. The second half should be given a new TRACKID that remain until next port. I also need the TRACKID to change when a new ship is introduced.

```
VESSEL      Date      Sailing/Port  TRACKID     
   1      01.02.2016    SAILING     1
   1      02.02.2016    SAILING     1
   1      03.02.2016    SAILING     1
   1      04.02.2016    SAILING     1
   1      05.02.2016    SAILING     1
   1      06.02.2016    PORT        1
   1      07.02.2016    PORT        1
   1      08.02.2016    PORT        2
   1      09.02.2016    PORT        2
   1      10.02.2016    SAILING     2
   2      11.02.2016    SAILING     3
   2      12.02.2016    SAILING     3
   2      13.02.2016    SAILING     3
   2      14.02.2016    PORT        3
   2      15.02.2016    PORT        4
   2      16.02.2016    SAILING     4
```

The answers below were able to create a TRACKID using sailed/port, but they did not take the new vessel into consideration. It is random if a track starts in port or sailing, and it the date is random as well.

Comment: What happens if you have an odd number of "PORT"s?

Comment: It does not matter how many "PORTs" are listed before the next TRACKID is generated. So for an odd number of 5, it does not matter if the TRACKID is generated after the 2nd or 3rd row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using `data.table::rleid` and `dplyr`. This uses run length encoding to first create a grouping variable based on `Sailing.Port` (`ID1`). For each group, set an indicator to 1 if it is the second half of a "PORT" and 0 otherwise (`ID2`). Using that indicator, replace `ID1` with another rle grouping variable, and generate `TRACKID` with `cumsum`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  group_by(ID1 = rleid(Sailing.Port)) %>%
  mutate(ID2 = if_else((row_number() > n()/2) & Sailing.Port == "PORT", 1, 0))  %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(ID1 = rleid(ID2)) %>%
  mutate(ID3 = if_else(ID2 == 1 & row_number() == 1, 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(TRACKID = cumsum(ID3)+1) %>%
  select(-ID1, -ID2, -ID3)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
   Date       Sailing.Port TRACKID
   <fct>      <fct>          <dbl>
 1 01.02.2016 SAILING            1
 2 02.02.2016 SAILING            1
 3 03.02.2016 SAILING            1
 4 04.02.2016 SAILING            1
 5 05.02.2016 SAILING            1
 6 06.02.2016 PORT               1
 7 07.02.2016 PORT               1
 8 08.02.2016 PORT               2
 9 09.02.2016 PORT               2
10 10.02.2016 SAILING            2
11 11.02.2016 SAILING            2
12 12.02.2016 SAILING            2
13 13.02.2016 SAILING            2
14 14.02.2016 PORT               2
15 15.02.2016 PORT               3
16 16.02.2016 SAILING            3
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:16, .Label = c("01.02.2016", 
"02.02.2016", "03.02.2016", "04.02.2016", "05.02.2016", "06.02.2016", 
"07.02.2016", "08.02.2016", "09.02.2016", "10.02.2016", "11.02.2016", 
"12.02.2016", "13.02.2016", "14.02.2016", "15.02.2016", "16.02.2016"
), class = "factor"), Sailing.Port = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("PORT", 
"SAILING"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", "Sailing.Port"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been using your scripts with great success, but I have one issue I cant get around. I have expanded the table two contain one more column with a ship identifier code. Is there any way to modify the script such as for each time it gets to a new vessel, it will start on a new route? It is possible for me to add the value "new_ship" into Sailing.Port for the first row of each ship. Or else the the additional column has to be used: c(SHIP1, SHIP1, SHIP1, .... SHIP2, SHIP2, SHIP 2, .......SHIP3, etc)

Comment: @Jonas Perhaps you should edit your question to show what you mean.

Comment: Thank you, I will do it that way that the next time. I just figured out what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without `for` and using the tidyverse and the zoo package (for `na.locf`). It creates a different sequence number "a" for each consecutive sequence of SAILING or PORT and then changes the beginning and the end of each ("PORT",a) group to the respectively previous or next SAILING group.

```
group_number <- (function(){i = 0L; function() i <<- i+1L })()

df %>% 
  mutate(id=row_number(),
         a=ifelse(is.na(lag(Sailing.Port))|(lag(Sailing.Port)!=Sailing.Port),id,NA)) %>%
  mutate(a=na.locf(a)) %>%         # propagate the id of the 1st row of sequence
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(g=group_number()) %>%
  mutate(g=ifelse(Sailing.Port=="PORT",ifelse(row_number()<=(n()/2),g-1,g+1),g)) %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-a,-id)
## A tibble: 16 x 3
#   Date       Sailing.Port     g
#   <fct>      <fct>        <dbl>
# 1 01.02.2016 SAILING          1
# 2 02.02.2016 SAILING          1
# 3 03.02.2016 SAILING          1
# 4 04.02.2016 SAILING          1
# 5 05.02.2016 SAILING          1
# 6 06.02.2016 PORT             1
# 7 07.02.2016 PORT             1
# 8 08.02.2016 PORT             3
# 9 09.02.2016 PORT             3
#10 10.02.2016 SAILING          3
#11 11.02.2016 SAILING          3
#12 12.02.2016 SAILING          3
#13 13.02.2016 SAILING          3
#14 14.02.2016 PORT             3
#15 15.02.2016 PORT             5
#16 16.02.2016 SAILING          5
```

Comment: You can combine two consecutive `mutate` calls into one, with each variable separated by a comma.

Comment: @avid_userR I knew that (as you can see in the first mutate), but my intent was to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over a new vector. Something like this.

```
temp.id<-1
for(n in 2:N){
 if(status[n]=="port" & status[n-1]=="sailing"){
  temp.id<-temp.id+1
 }
 leg[n]<-temp.id
}
```

That only gets you the first day in port. To find the midpoint, you would need a second loop inside. Something like this.

```
temp.days<-0
for(m in (n+1):N){
 temp.days<-temp.days+1
 if(status[m]=="sailing"){break}
}
```

Then, you'd need to do some arithmetic and figure out how to handle an odd number of days.